# Calculating an integral involving Haar measure on orthogonal projections

Tags: integration, haar-measure

Let $\sigma_{n, m}$ denote the uniform measure over matrices $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ satisfying $U^T U = I_m$. Let $1_k \in \mathbb{R}^k$ denote the vector with all entries equal to $1$.
I am trying to calculate, for $m < n$, the following quantity
$$
\mathcal{I}(n, m) = \int \frac{1}{1 - \tfrac{1}{n}\langle U^T 1_n, U^T 1_n \rangle} \, d \sigma_{n,m}(U) = \int\frac{1}{1 - \langle U^T v, U^T v \rangle } d\sigma_{n,m}(U), 
$$
where the final equality holds for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with unit Euclidean norm, simply using that $\sigma_{n, m}$ is unitarily invariant.

Is there a convenient way to calculate this Haar integral?

Comment: isn't this average divergent? $\langle U^\top v,U^\top v\rangle$ will equal to 1 with a nonzero probability

Comment: Sorry why is that the case?

Comment: Have you tried the case $n=m=2$?

Comment: I have entered an explicit calculation for $n=2$, $m=1$, to demonstrate the divergence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average diverges. To check this, try $n=2$, $m=1$; the matrix $U={u_1\choose u_2}$ has probability density
$$P(u_1,u_2)=\frac{2}{\pi}\delta(1-u_1^2-u_2^2).$$
Then, taking $v={1\choose 0}$,
$$\int \frac{1}{1-\langle U^\top v,U^\top v\rangle}\,d\sigma(U)=\int_{-1}^{1}du_1\int_{-1}^1 du_2 \, \frac{P(u_1,u_2)}{1-u_1^2}$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(1-u_1^2)^{3/2}}du_1=\infty.$$